# How to sort file list in helm-find-files

Tags: helm, helm-for-files

When I use `helm-find-files` to search for a directory. I would like it to display exact matches and directories first in the list of candidates, followed by files.

For example, searching for "src" gives the following results:

[image: helm-example]

How can I make "src" show up first, since it's an exact match and also a directory? Or, baring that, making hidden "." files go to the end of the list (since it seems to be in alphabetical order?)

Comment: `^src$` should match only `src`.

Comment: @abo-abo yeah, I know I could add regexp for it, but I'd like to change the default sort order when it's not specified

Comment: Are you aware of the new flex matching, and do you want to turn it off? If you want this sort behavior with flex matching enabled (which it is by default), then I think the helm devs are working on it, but it's not ready yet.

Comment: @PythonNut I'd prefer to keep the flex matching on, so hopefully the helm devs will get it fixed soon!

Comment: @PythonNut Unrelated, but I'd like to know how to turn the flex matching off. Preferrably in every helm command, but mostly in helm-find-files, helm-mini, and helm-recentf.

Comment: @LeeH [the github issue](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/issues/145) is the source for all information helm-fuzzy related at the moment.

Comment: @nanny I think fuzzy matching is off by default for all commands, except `helm-find-files`. See [Fuzzy Matching](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm#fuzzy-matching) section for a list of commands that have fuzzy matching (which is disabled by default). Or are you using `helm-projectile`? I am planning to add an option to disable fuzzy-matching.

Comment: @LeeH You should update to the latest Helm. It is fixed now. A new custom variable is added: `helm-find-files-sort-directories`. To enable your desired behavior, set it to `t`.

Comment: For some reason the change was hard to spot, but indeed it is there, in [this commit](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/commit/063cef69aa5d88f20d15c7dc272579a9f6d5ce8f).  However, the variable is not there in the [current version of the file as of today](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/blob/master/helm-files.el).

Answer (score 2):

According to the comments from @Tu Do above, apparently that was possible at one time, but the feature has been taken out in commit [8489bee](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/commit/8489bee0ceb9076b0d9ad8f19af63bcd730177b8) and related commits.

Comment: BTW, the interested reader might find my answer at http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/12745/how-to-sort-file-list-in-helm-find-files-by-date can be reused in this context, if you're willing to modify `helm-files.el` locally.