# How to sort file list in helm-find-files by date

Tags: helm, shell

[How to sort file list in helm-find-files](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/5929/8406) asks how to sort the file list so that directories float to the top.  My question is different:

Is it possible to sort the files returned by `helm-find-files` so that they appear sorted by *modification time*, rather than *alphabetical order* (i.e., as if they had been listed by `ls -lt` rather than `ls -la`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "Yes -- use the source."

With a little help from [StackOverflow | Emacs — sort list of directories / files by modification date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26514437/emacs-sort-list-of-directories-files-by-modification-date)...  Here's a modified version of `helm-ff-directory-files` that does the job.   Note that you should `(require 'files)` to get this working.

```
(defun helm-ff-directory-files (directory)
  "List contents of DIRECTORY.
Argument FULL mean absolute path.
It is same as `directory-files' but always returns the
dotted filename '.' and '..' even on root directories in Windows
systems."
  (setq directory (file-name-as-directory
                   (expand-file-name directory)))
  (let* (file-error
         (ls   (mapcar #'car
                       (sort (directory-files-and-attributes
                              directory 'full
                              directory-files-no-dot-files-regexp t)
                             #'(lambda (x y)
                                 (not (time-less-p (nth 6 x) (nth 6 y)))))))
         (dot  (concat directory "."))
         (dot2 (concat directory "..")))
    (puthash directory (+ (length ls) 2) helm-ff--directory-files-hash)
    (append (and (not file-error) (list dot dot2)) ls)))
```

Comment: This answer does not look too useful to a future visitor. What are you suggesting to do with this code? Patch the package source with it? This is not very user-friendly, and you will have to do it every time the package is updated.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  It motivated me to raise this issue: [helm-emacs #1041](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/issues/1041) My opinion is that future visitors should learn how to use the source, and that this answer is instructive in that regard.  I **don't** mean to imply that this patch should be maintained forever, just that it shows how to address the question.  A more complicated answer would make this behavior an option, and provide nicer integration.  This answer is a proof-of-concept. I think it is up to the package maintainer to make an easy-to-use version, if that desired.

Comment: @T.Verron I've replaced the old patch with a more user-friendly snippet of lisp code.

Comment: Wooud it be work if I just past it into the `.emacs` file , I am having following warning message: `reference to free variable ‘helm-ff--directory-files-hash`@Joe Corneli

Comment: I think this is now supported by mainline helm. Check issue number 1041 above.